# What to make of the following sentences that begin with why, when, where, or how?

Tags: adverbs, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, questions

> - Why you put yourself in this predicament is beyond me.
> - When you leave for work is of your concern.
> - Where we spend the night depends on the weather.
> - How you finish the project is unimportant.

I feel they are relative adverbs (fused) or free nominal constructions. But I fear I'm completely off.

Comment: @deadrat No, at least one of these  includes an interrogative clause functioning as Subject. Three of them are ambiguous between the a fused relative and an interrogative. A fourth is marginally interpretable as an interrogative clause. Also the OP's question clearly requires an explanation of the difference between the function of the  relative word and the function of the clause. Lastly these don't introduce relative clauses, even if we think they are not interrogatives.

Comment: @deadrat because there's no antecedent - which is why the OP is having trouble deciding what they are.

Comment: Please see also: [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris Why? Is the OP a language learner? I didn't think so. I thought they wanted to understand the complicated and ambiguous syntax underpinning these constructions, including the synactic functions of the *wh-* words within the Subjects. It seems like a good fit for this site and a poor one for ELL. We don't get much call for syntactic analyses of *free nominals* / *fused relatives* / *interrogative content clauses* over there ...

Comment: @Araucaria  Well, that's a fair cop, but see Lawler's comment to rogermue's answer at my cite.  The clauses concern themselves with the things that adverbs do (time, place, manner) but they act like nouns taking the place of the implied answer to their (embedded) interrogatories ("The place where we spend the night....")

Comment: @deadrat Yes, granted. (Still not a dupe though!)

Comment: @Araucaria True enough:  not all things possible obtain

Comment: @Araucaria Please note the "also" in the comment. And, because a suitable answer may already exist **even** there. So much trouble for you just because of a hasty interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are off the mark.

They are all *noun phrases*.  Each phrase (up to the verb) is the subject of its sentence.

Comment: Are you saying that fused relatives *aren't* noun phrases? (For  me they aren't necessarily). I'm pretty certain in your grammmar you consider fused relative constructions as noun phrases.

Comment: I'm just sayin' what I'm sayin'. I don't have a clue about "fused relative", but I know a dang noun phrase when I see one. And every one of them is the subject of its sentence, no matter what you call it.

Comment: The OP's asking whether they're "free nominals" or not. Most of them could be interpreted as such. So in a way our OP's not *off the mark*. That's what I was angling at.  I agree that traditional grammars would regard these all as NPs, but it's not quite what the OP's asking about, that's all :) That's not my downvote, btw!!!!

Comment: Sorry-- missed the "free nominal" in question, and I'm not familiar with the term. Is that what you would call what I have been calling NPs?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and yes, it is the lack of an antecedent that is confusing. That is why I felt they were fused, being themselves the 'antecedent'. Or am I mixing concepts?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Yes, they're usually NP's. But as to what kind of NP (i.e. what is the structure of this NP), they're probably fused relatives/"free nominals". Fused relatives look like a relative clause with no antecedent word. So instead of something like *The thing which you did yesterday* we'll see *What you did yesterday*. In this construction the *wh-* word is performing two functions, it's both the head of the clause (it's the thing that the rest of the clause is modifying) and also it represents the realtivised element in the clause i.e. it might represent an Object within that clause

Comment: @ArturReikdal No, that's quite right :) If I get time later I *might* try and write you an answer, but no promises ...EDIT [These page here, 191-2](http://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar)   from  A Student's Introduction to English Grammar by Huddleston & Pullum might help. They call them *fused relatives*. But!!!! Take care, look at their bit on interrogative content clauses at the end of that section!!!

Comment: @Araucaria I hope you find the time, which I understand can be a rare commodity.  And thanks for abjuring the downvote, which leaves the erroneous impression that BH's answer is wrong.