# Do I need a comma before "which"?

Tags: punctuation

> I need this flag because I need to show to others, which country I am
>   from.

Do I need a comma before "which" in this sentence?

Comment: If you add a comma, the sentence means that you'd like to show where others are from, not where you are from.

Comment: Interestingly, this related question (where the clause acts as _subject_) was submitted just moments before yours!  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273903/what-to-make-of-the-following-sentences-that-begin-with-why-when-where-or-how

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not include a comma before which.

"Which country I am from" is an [essential clause](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/) that is required for the sentence to make sense.

Comment: @SomethingDark  Do you mean a comma before or after which?

Comment: @rogermue - Well... both, really. But "before" answers the question that was asked. No idea why I typed "after."

Comment: And the essential clause acts nounal, in that it forms the direct object of _show_